# Не выводит значения таблицы при их существовании (SQLite)

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

День добрый. Столкнулся с проблемой когда заканчивал программу. У меня изначально было подключение к MySQL бд, но после я импортировал в SQLite для более удобного использования. В ней было две таблицы на момент переноса. После подключения через локальную, создал еще одну, проверил в DB Browser, заполнил значениями для проверки, однако при выводе ничего не показывает.

[image: 1]

Таблица department с которой работаю

Часть кода с запросом для вывода значений

```
public List<String> AllDepartments() {

    List<String> departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    String sqlite = "SELECT * FROM depart";

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getSQLiteConnect().prepareStatement(sqlite);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            int idDepart = resultSet.getInt(Const.DEPARTMENT_ID);
            String departName = resultSet.getString(Const.DEPARTMENT_NAME);
            String count = resultSet.getString(Const.DEPARTMENT_COUNT);

            String Info = String.format("\t%d \t%s \t\t%s ", idDepart, departName, count);
            departmentList.add(Info);


        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return departmentList;
}
```

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)